# Adding a pixel value to a CSS percentage variable

Tags: css, css-variables

I am creating a video box for an iframe which is working well.  It takes a css variable argument 16/9 and will use that to calculate the percentage of padding that is needed for the video to display the in the correct aspect ratio (in this case it is 16/9).

I have an issue where I have a playlist div which adds an extra 50px to the box that is getting calculated - this is the CSS.  For this padding bottom I need to add an extra 50px to the padding if a certain condition is met?  How would you do this using calc?

```
  [style*="--aspect-ratio"]::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
    }
```

This does not work as it is a percentage value - that is calculated from the calc?

```
[style*="--aspect-ratio"]::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio + 50)));
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `var(--aspect-ratio) + 50` because `50` is not part of the variable name, which is all that is passed as the first argument to `var`.

Comment: Additionally, you need the unit for `50` - by itself, `50` doesn't mean anything, you'd need `50px`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your code like below:

```
padding-bottom: calc((100% / var(--aspect-ratio)) + 50px);
```

You divide the percentage with the ratio and then you add `50px`